# why ip 192.168.1.1 is default ip for routers?

Tags: networking, ip

I've seen this IP address is used much in many routers settings but i don't understand why it has much importance?Is there any specific reason for ip address 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address) and [this](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-private-ip-address-2625970).

Answer (score 2):

i'll try to answer your question as better as i can (i'm not an expert so if you find inaccuracies please edit my answer or correct me on comments, thanks!)

**192.168.1.1** is the first node ip avaible of the private class c ip, wich range is from **192.168.0.1** to **192.168.255.255**, (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) for more information), the private ip are used on private networks, so there can be infinite numbers of same private ip on internet, it doesn't matter because it is considerable only on your LAN network, contrariwise pubblic ip are unique for all internet nodes, so the question can be why private network ip are chosen on this range? well i'll try to answer this

> why 192?

**191.255.255.255** = 10111111.11111111.11111111.11111111

**192.0.0.0** = 11000000.0000000.0000000.0000000

because it is the first number wich first 2 binary state result to be 1,
(2^7 + 2^6)

> why 168 for private networks?

it has being used since the very begin of internet so that is intresting, but i think it is random, there is not true motivation for that number as i know.

> why .0.1 or .1.1?

is that the first number rappresent the nid (network id), so 
**192.68.0.20** is on the same network of **192.168.0.40** and different network of **192.168.200.1**, so .0.x and .1.x are the first 2 network ip avaibles, the last digit rappresent the hid(host id) which can go from 1 to 254, because .0 is rappresent the network and .255 rappresent the broadcast,so the very first node avaible is usually used for the default gateway, (.254 is used often too) and  in common LAN is handly to have the router ip on the first host ip avaible, so you always know what is the router ip

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918:

> **Private Address Space**
>
> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

```
 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

Notice that `192.168.0.0` has the smallest space reserved. The reason why 192.168.0.1 or similar ones (eg. 192.168.1.1) are so common is that it falls within the smallest private address space `(192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255)`.

As most routers are generally programmed to use the first available IP address as its own, routers are commonly found on: `192.168.1.1. 192.168.0.1. 192.168.100.1. 10.0.1.1. 10.0.0.1. 172.16.1.1. 172.16.0.1.`

Answer (score 1):

> why ip 192.168.1.1 is default ip for routers?

It really isn't. There is no standard that sets this as a default. [*RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) defines the three address ranges for private addressing:

> 3. Private Address Space
>
> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
> following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:
>
> ```
>  10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>  172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>  192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
> ```
>
> We will refer to the first block as "24-bit block", the second as
> "20-bit block", and to the third as "16-bit" block. Note that (in
> pre-CIDR notation) the first block is nothing but a single class A
> network number, while the second block is a set of 16 contiguous
> class B network numbers, and third block is a set of 256 contiguous
> class C network numbers.

The RFC actually recommends using addressing from the `10.0.0.0/8` range:

> If a suitable subnetting scheme can be designed and is supported by
> the equipment concerned, it is advisable to use the 24-bit block
> (class A network) of private address space and make an addressing plan
> with a good growth path. If subnetting is a problem, the 16-bit block
> (class C networks), or the 20-bit block (class B networks) of private
> address space can be used.

Actual business-grade routers have no default addressing at all. There is noting in IP itself that determines what is private or public addressing. The private address ranges were (somewhat arbitrarily) defined by the IETF with IANA. A router really has no idea what is private or public addressing, and any valid IP addressing can be used on a router interface. Routers are often addressed with only public addressing, or addressed with only private addressing.

Your question seems to indicate consumer-grade routers, which are often resource-poor, cheaply made, and designed to be used by people who do not really understand networking. Consumer-grade routers are designed to connect a private network with the public Internet, so they need to default to private addressing and NAT to public addressing.

The manufacturers often pre-define the private addressing used by the router, and they configure the router to use addressing from the old Class C range in order to give the smallest network size under the old classful routing. Also, there used to be an RFC that did not allow the use of the "zero subnet" of a classful address range (which would have prohibited use of the `192.168.0.0/24` network).

Both classful routing and the prohibition against using the zero subnet are long gone. RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519 defined CIDR (*Classless* Inter-Domain Routing) that deprecated the old classful networking. RFC 1878 clarified that the use of the all-zeros and all-ones subnets are allowed.

The consumer-grade manufacturers seemingly think that if it isn't broken, then don't fix it, and they continue to pre-define the private addressing on their routers with the `192.168.1.0/24` network. The full `192.168.1.1` address for the router LAN interface is simply the first usable host address in the network for the LAN interface in the `192.168.1.0/24` network. Many people use the first host address, some people use the last host address, for the router interface address. A router can actually use any valid host address (a router is a host on a network that knows how to forward traffic to other networks) in a network for an interface, but it helps to be consistent, and using the first valid host address is the most common practice.